# Whitelist for redirect URLs in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security

We have a security issue in our project. An attacker can intercept a login request and modify a 'Host' header in it. The server would respond with a redirect (303), sending user to a possibly evil site.

Is it possible to add a whitelist for redirects?

Using Spring-boot with embedded tomcat, in production this whole thing will be behind a load balancer.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http  //@formatter:off
        .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("...")
            .usernameParameter("...")
            .passwordParameter("...")
            .loginPage("/").permitAll()
            .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
        .and().logout().permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
            .deleteCookies(XSRF_TOKEN, JSESSIONID)
        .and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("...").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository)
        .and().addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);//@formatter:on
}
```

Until now I have tried the following:

1. to use `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` and adding a Valve there.
2. to use `FilterRegistrationBean` and using a `RemoteAddrFilter.setDeny()`.

The 1° option wouldn't start at all. I'm obviously making mistakes somewhere, but this information is hard to find and I don't have the complete picture in my head of what to do.

The 2° option I found here on `Stackoverflow` and it feels the right thing to do, but I failed to make it work. If `setDeny()` is present, it wouldn't even let me enter my web-site. If I comment it out, then looks like no filtering happen at all. The bean looks like this:

```
@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean remoteAddressFilter() {

        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        RemoteAddrFilter filter = new RemoteAddrFilter();

        filter.setDeny("attacker/.com.*");
        filter.setDenyStatus(404);

        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(filter);
        filterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");

        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: *An attacker can intercept a login request and modify* You could use HTTPS, to solve that problem.

Comment: *The server would respond with a redirect (303), sending user to a possibly evil site.* Why is your server sending the user to a evil site? The redirects are configured in your handlers.

Comment: *Is it possible to add a whitelist for redirects?* On client-site? Why do you change the server code to implement a whitelist on client-site?

Comment: How should `RemoteAddrFilter#setDeny` help you? Did you read the documentation of this method? BTW: Are you sure, that it works with DNS names, too?

Comment: @dur
_The redirects are configured in your handlers._
How can I configure them? Spring security just returns 303 and that's all.

_On client-site? Why do you change the server code to implement a whitelist on client-site?_
No, it is a server which is respoinding with a redirect. The request has left the front end and was intercepted, modified and then sent to server, which returned 303.

_Did you read the documentation of this method?_
Yes I find it undescriptive.

Answer (score 1):

This is an Old question. But adding an answer as Spring has added support for whitelisting in Spring security `4.2.17` and `5.2`. This might be useful for others who stumble on same thing 
 In security config,

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
        firewall.setAllowedHostnames(Arrays.asList("myhostname1","myhostname2"));
        web.httpFirewall(firewall);
    }
```

It will throw `org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException`
with message like "The request was rejected because the domain `www.attackersite.com` is untrusted."

If you don't want all the features of StrictHttpFirewall, you can extend HttpFirewall and add your own implementation.